# malloc of array in struct passed as argument

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I would like to allocate memory for arrays that are members of a struct I need to use, inside a function that takes the struct as an argument.

```
arg->A.size=(int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

will not compile (request for member 'size' is something not a structure.

```
arg->A->size=(int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

will throw a segmentation fault error

Any help will be appreciated.
Here is the code, thanks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// struct A 
struct A {
    int dim;                // dimensions
    int* size;              // points per dim array
    double* val;            // values stored in array
    int total;              // pow(size,dim) 
};

// struct B that uses A
struct B {
    int tag;
    struct A* A;
};

int function_AB(struct B* B);

int main(void){
    struct B B;
    function_AB(&B);

    return 0;
}

int function_AB(struct B* arg){
    int N=10;
    arg->tag=99;
    printf("tag assigned = %d \n", arg->tag);
    arg->A->size=(int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have structure pointer in another structure, first you need to allocate memory for that. then allocate the memory for structure members!

```
struct B {
    int tag;
    struct A* A;
};
```

Here `A` is a pointer to a structure called `A`. First allocate memory for this, then allocate memory for the elements of `struct A`

```
arg->A = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
```

then do-

```
arg->A->size = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Try the following changes in your `int function_AB(struct B* arg)`-

```
int function_AB(struct B* arg){
int N=10;
arg->tag=99;
printf("tag assigned = %d \n", arg->tag);

arg->A = malloc(sizeof(struct A)); // First allocate the memory for struct A* A; 

arg->A->size = malloc(N*sizeof(int)); // Allocate the memory for struct A members
arg->A->val = malloc(N*sizeof(double));

// do your stuff

// free the allocated memories here
free(arg->A->size);
free(arg->A->val);
free(arg->A);

return 0;
}
```

And don't cast the result of `malloc()`!

Comment: So far I think Sathish was right (extending the change already suggested by downhillFromHere on the first answer). Implementing it inside the function is exactly what I was looking for, so that I specifically use arg->A = malloc(sizeof(struct A)) instruction regardless of prior/after assignment of values. I still would use malloc int and double casting for size and val. Is there any reason to avoid doing so? I still have to figure out about whether I must use free for A, size and val before the function return. I will update if something goes wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mae In c `malloc` will allocate the memory and return the appropriate pointer to the allocated memory! If you found this answer is helpful don't forgot to validate it!

Comment: You're right. Bad practice due to migration from C++ on which it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

You simply haven't allocated memory for `struct A *A`. Before assigning anything to `A->size` you would first need to do something like

```
B->A = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
```

Answer (score 1):

The second case is correct, but crashes because the A inside the B declared in main has not been assigned a value.  You probably want something like

```
struct A A;
struct B B;
B.A = &A;

function_AB(&B);
```